# How to run windows bash in C#

Tags: c#, linux, windows, bash, visual-studio

I want to run the following command in bash (Linux Subsystem in Windows) :

```
bash -c "ls"
```

And use it in C# like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("bash", "-c \"ls\"");
Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();
```

But it gives me the exception below:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified
  NativeErrorCode=2
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\matin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**Edit:**

I can successfully run a batch file contains my command. But I want to grab the output like the code below:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("file.bat");
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
while (!p.HasExited)
    Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

But it prints:

```
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Have you tried `new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe")` ?

Comment: Try the full path name of bash

Comment: @cup no difference

Comment: If the full name has spaces in it, the name needs to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Can we assume that `ls` is a placeholder for a more complex sequence of commands?  Running this in `bash -c` by itself is rather pointless.

Comment: @tripleee Yes your assume is right. it is a placeholder for a more complex command.

Answer (score 4):

The file cannot be found due to [Windows Filesystem Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for 32-bit apps. You have to compile your .NET app as x64 in order to launch `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`.

If you try and set `RedirectStandardOutput` to `true`, however, all you'll get is `E r r o r :   0 x 8 0 0 7 0 0 5 7` which corresponds to Win32's `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

One thing I have discovered is that if you do not set any of the `Redirect` properties to true, Bash appears to inherit the current console, however you can't then even redirect standard output on the .NET program that launches bash... it would appear that Windows currently doesn't support redirecting output from a Linux Subsystem application into a Win32 one.

Comment: That was my case - I did compile my app with Any CPU as target. After switching to x64 the file not found problem disappeared. That `E r r o r :   0 x 8 0 0 7 0 0 5 7` problem is an known WSL issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2) and is already fixed in insider build.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to create the batch file below:

```
bash -c "ls > log.txt"
```

And use the C# program below:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("file.bat");
Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("log.txt"));
```

The output will be written in `log.txt` file.

But it has some problems:

1. It opens a cmd window in order to run the batch file.
2. You can not read the output until the process is exited.
3. You can not redirect the standard input

So the problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this if i understood your problem this may help.

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "bash -c \"time\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```